# angularjs using $http.post to PHP but getting empty array

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, post

Right now I have a basic post request using the $http service in angular. I'm seeing everything find in console.log with a status of 200 (successful), but in PHP no luck. I've tried using JSON_decode, I've tried the $_POST (var_dump) no luck. Please assist if you can think of a solution.

app.js

```
 var postData={
            firstName:'something',
            lastName:'here'
    };
    postData=JSON.stringify(postData);
    $http({method:'POST',url:'sendmail.php',data:postData,headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
        .success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log('Success' + data); 
        })
        .error(function (data, status,headers,config) {
            // uh oh
            console.log('error' + status + data);
        });
```

sendmail.php

```
$args = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo $args->firstName;
```

In my php file I am getting the following error.

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-new-project/sendmail.php on line 3

however, in my console.log I am getting:

Successsomething

Also, I have a live site with the same problem.

Just to reiterate no matter what I do, (add headers, JSON decode) PHP array remains empty.

Comment: `$http` automatically stringifies your objects. Skip that step in your code

Comment: Is sendmail expecting an array?  If so try adding 'true' as a second argument to your json decode call.

Comment: dont understand what you mean by if it is expecting an array. I've tried var_dump($data) and var_dump($_POST) and both are empty. Also, tried true but no luck....is there a way to send to a javascript file to see if the data is making it there?

Comment: ok, here is the question....in my php file I do the following...
echo $_POST['firstName'];
echo $_POST['lastName'];

when doing this, it goes out to my console log. Therefore it's like the php file is working, however I can't get this to echo on the actual PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

When you $http.post() in AngularJS, you can get the parameters in PHP from the $_POST array like:

```
echo $_POST['firstName'];
```

If $_POST is empty, then you a problem somewhere else.

Try isolating your problem.
You can use Postman, HTTPRequester or any other Firefox/Chrome plugin to simulate a request to your PHP script.

Make your PHP script work first, then make your AngularJS post request work.

Answer (score 0):

This actually has to do with how Angular passes the data. By default is serialized to JSON format which creates the issue with PHP.

I'm going to presume that your data is coming from some inputs or something like that. It's better to use ng-model on the form fields

Basically you have to pass a custom header in the request. In this code I'm just using a single input:

```
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : 'your_url',
  data    : 'data-name=' + $scope.yourValue,//in PHP then you look for $_POST['data-name']
  headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(
  // success callback
  function(response){
    // success code
  },
  // error callback
  function(response){
    // success code
  }
);
```

In order to get a better grasp of how to do this read this article:

[Forms in AngularJS](http://tutsnare.com/post-form-data-using-angularjs/)